# jQuery Pagination plugin with ASP.NET gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can we implement pagination for an asp:gridview which has 'n' number of records retrieved from a database using a [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) pagination plug-in. If so how can we implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) implementation since the ASP gridview control has pagination built in.

I don't think the gridview would be very helpful in this case. 1) Because it isn't intended to be used that way and 2) you'd be wasting a lot of overhead on formatting.

A better idea would be to design something that takes JSON result sets based on pagination data from [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) and have jQuery render the layout on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a repeater + jquery like explained [here](http://naspinski.net/post/GridView-SortingPaging--REAL-AJAX-with-AspNet-Series.aspx)